# jmeter headless creating massive number of live threads as viewed in visual vm. Out of memory error

Tags: java, jmeter

I've been using jmeter for a while now but it's my first attempt using a headless instance.

I've created a single Test Plan with two thread groups.

TG1: generates a source file of sample data. (432000 sample records)
TG2: uses the sample data to fire of requests to another application.

This works ok over short periods but when I run it over longer periods it dies with an Out of Memory error.

I've reviewed the running application using visualvm and can see that the active thread count is 14,000+ almost from start up. The Used Heap shoots up and continues to death.

the test is expected to create 432000 threads over a ramp up period of 43200 seconds. this is 10 threads per second over 12 hours.

Interestingly the non-headless build lasts longer than the headless build with no listeners attached.

I'm not sure where these threads are coming from? I'm assuming they are the threads that are to be fired off, are they created up front?

I'm missing something here.

**EDIT**

I've already tried 'delay thread creation until needed' option. The threads are still created in advance and I have the same issue.

Comment: How much memory have you allocated to Jmeter?

Comment: what is hw config of load generator machine and heap allocated to Jmeter instance? 432000 is very high no. of threads for single machine. you should avoid all listeners, reporters, assertions and run in nonui mode. If you are already following same then probably you should look for distributed jmeter instances and testing.

Comment: Try this:  https://medium.com/@nirmalmewada/unveiling-the-secret-achieving-50k-concurrent-user-load-using-jmeter-with-2-5g-ram-only-51f892b233ce

Answer (score 2):

Headless mode is actually what is recommended for running JMeter Load Test.

What is your scenario? If it's for 432000 requests during 12 hours which stands for 10 requests per second only, than it looks like that your configuration is not very correct and you need to "tell" JMeter to hold the load at 10 requests per second rate using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).

If you're looking to create 432000 of **active** concurrent threads you need to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf), however I don't think that you really need so many concurrent threads.

Comment: "thumbs up" for the Constant Throughput Timer.